# 'UITextField' XCode 7

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, xcode7-beta3, ios-9-beta3

I have recently began working on app development more specifically games. I am using Xcode 7 beta 3 default iPhone 6 simulator. In my game I have a screen to enter the user's name setting up an action through interface builder 'primaryActionTriggered' in which I would update the high score file and dismiss the view.  It all worked perfectly in the simulator but when I put it on my iPhone 6 iOS 8.0.1 the action did not trigger. Has something changed in iOS 9 to change the way 'UITextField' works, and can you please provide a working example which I could see. The simulator was running iOS 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already explained the reason for the problem perfectly! The whole concept of a "primary action" is new in iOS 9. You cannot use it in an earlier system.

So, if you need compatibility with iOS 8, just pretend that the "primary action" trigger doesn't exist; hook your text field up with some other control event (such as Editing Changed).

Comment: I have tried using editing ended but I see no way to actually close the keyboard, so could you please explain to me what action I should use which activates when pressing the return key on the keyboard and how to modify it

Comment: I have made it work with editing did end. Thank you so much for your help